# Blink page title with same text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a blinking animation in page title with same content. Its like fadeout and fadein. I tried some way but where the blinking will happen with separate text. Here is my code:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var title = document.title;
    document.title = (title == "test" ? "none" : "test");
}, 1000);
```

How can I blink the title with same `"test"` content?

By the way, I do not want blank title, I know it is not possible. I want to blink title like on-off.

Comment: change `"none"` to `""`

Comment: working for me in firefox

Comment: @Grundy If I change "none" to "" then it is showing the URI in title

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I have a Blank Title Page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556255/how-can-i-have-a-blank-title-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace "none" with '\u200E'

```
setInterval(function(){
   var title = document.title;
   document.title = (title == "test" ? '\u200E' : "test");
}, 1000);
```

Works in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: This answer is derived from [How can I have a Blank Title Page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556255/how-can-i-have-a-blank-title-page) Thanks @Grundy

Comment: Thank you very much @anurupr