# Empty HTML page title

Tags: html, html-title

I was wondering if there is any possible way to set the title of a page to empty/transparent.

I have tried each of the following titles without success:

```
<title></title>
<title> </title>
<title>&nbsp;</title>
```

Using them, would keep the default title of the page, just like it would be without the code.

The closest I got was with `<title>.</title>`.

I'm using Chrome.

Comment: What is the aim? that the Tab shows something or nothing?

Comment: @mplungjan, [nothing](http://i.imgur.com/heEXtHE.png).

Comment: What does it displays when the title is empty ?

Comment: The browser shows the name of the file if the title is deemed empty

Comment: I forgot to ask why you want to do this?

Comment: @mplungjan, I don't know. I just like to test all the features I guess, and push the boundaries of the programming language.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is one that works in my Windows Chrome - Chrome seems to remove known spaces. This one comes from https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html

U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE ->﻿<- 
No width (the character is invisible)

---

HTML:

```
<title>&#65279;</title>
```

Comment: I don't suppose there's any way to remove the [title attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) right? I guess it's [not a big deal](http://i.imgur.com/g7NQ5s6.png).

Comment: I think if you remove it, you will have the page name again

Comment: Aren't you about to earn the [html gold badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/134/html)? :)

Comment: Just for the record, I tested out the other ones in the list of your [awesome link](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) and I found out that [`&#6158;`](https://unicode-table.com/en/180E/) and [`&#8203;`](https://unicode-table.com/en/200B/) also works. Another extra one, [`&#8206;`/`&lrm;`](https://unicode-table.com/en/200E/), which I found out in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23558385/7598088).

Comment: @J.Vie  I could mark as duplicate but I am using a different char ;)

Comment: @J.Vie Got a "Nice answer" AND "Enlightened" badge for this one too :)